# Can't update User informations MongoDB validation error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Why can't I Update User if my passwordConfirm is required: true? This is my User model:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please tell us your name!'],
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please provide your email'],
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
    validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Please provide a valid email'],
  },
  photo: {
    type: String,
    default: 'default.jpg',
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['user', 'guide', 'lead-guide', 'admin'],
    default: 'user',
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please provide a password'],
    minlength: 8,
    select: false,
  },
  passwordConfirm: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please confirm your password'],
    validate: {
      validator: function (el) {
        return el === this.password;
      },
      message: 'Passwords are not the same!',
    },
  },
  passwordChangedAt: Date,
  passwordResetToken: String,
  passwordResetExpires: Date,
  active: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
    select: false,
  },
});

userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  // Only run this function if password was actually modified
  if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();

  // Hash the password with cost of 12
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 12);

  // Delete passwordConfirm field
  this.passwordConfirm = undefined;
  next();
});

userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified('password') || this.isNew) return next();

  this.passwordChangedAt = Date.now() - 1000;
  next();
});

userSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
  // this points to the current query
  this.find({ active: { $ne: false } });
  next();
});

userSchema.methods.correctPassword = async function (
  candidatePassword,
  userPassword
) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, userPassword);
};

userSchema.methods.changedPasswordAfter = function (JWTTimestamp) {
  if (this.passwordChangedAt) {
    const changedTimestamp = parseInt(
      this.passwordChangedAt.getTime() / 1000,
      10
    );

    return JWTTimestamp < changedTimestamp;
  }

  // False means NOT changed
  return false;
};

userSchema.methods.createPasswordResetToken = function () {
  const resetToken = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');

  this.passwordResetToken = crypto
    .createHash('sha256')
    .update(resetToken)
    .digest('hex');

  console.log({ resetToken }, this.passwordResetToken);

  this.passwordResetExpires = Date.now() + 10 * 60 * 1000;

  return resetToken;
};

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

And this is my controller:

```
exports.updateUserProfile = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);

  if (user) {
    user.name = req.body.name || user.name;
    user.email = req.body.email || user.email;
    if (req.body.password) {
      user.password = req.body.password;
    }

    const updatedUser = await user.save();

    res.json({
      name: updatedUser.name,
    });
  } else {
    res.status(404);
    throw new Error('User not found');
  }
});
```

res.json doesn't matter, I just want to get something back except error..

This is error from postman:

```
"error": {
        "errors": {
            "passwordConfirm": {
                "name": "ValidatorError",
                "message": "Please confirm your password",
                "properties": {
                    "message": "Please confirm your password",
                    "type": "required",
                    "path": "passwordConfirm"
                },
                "kind": "required",
                "path": "passwordConfirm"
            }
        },
        "_message": "User validation failed",
        "statusCode": 500,
        "status": "error",
        "name": "ValidationError",
        "message": "User validation failed: passwordConfirm: Please confirm your password"
    },
```

When I remove required: true code passwordConfirm then it does everything properly, I do not require anywhere in the controller to change the password or something like that

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
 exports.updateUserProfile = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
      const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
      
       const userToSave = {}
       
    
      if (user) {
        const userToSave = Object.assign({}, user)

        userToSave.name = req.body.name || user.name;
        userToSave.email = req.body.email || user.email;
        if (req.body.password) {
          userToSave.password = req.body.password;
        }
         const dbSave = new User(userToSave);
         await dbSave.save();
    
        res.json({
          name: updatedUser.name,
        });
      } else {
        res.status(404);
        throw new Error('User not found');
      }
    });
```

Comment: I got this error: "message": "user is not a constructor",

Comment: Please I made some editing...

Comment: Check it out there was a mistake... user with capital U User

Comment: @valkkorn any updates?